# Как преобразовать строку в число python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
l = []

s = input("Введите число: ")
l=list(s)

a = l[0:3]
b = l[3:6]
```

`a = "123"` нужно преобразовать в `a = 123`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [12]: inp = input("Enter: ")
Enter: 123456

In [13]: a, b = int(inp[:3]), int(inp[3:6])

In [14]: a, b
Out[14]: (123, 456)
```

Answer (score 4):

Сразу получить число: `a = int(input())`

Answer (score 1):

```
переменная = int(переменная)
```

Вот и все :)

Answer (score 0):

попробуй сделать так

```
a = int(a)
```

Comment: TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'

Answer (score 0):

Вот так вот:

```
s = input("Введите число: ")
num = int(s)

print(num)
```

Для первых и вторых троек:

```
s = input("Введите число: ")
first_three = int(s[0:3])
second_three = int(s[3:6])

print(first_three)
print(second_three)
```

Comment: Мне надо как то выделить от 0:3 и от 3:6

Answer (score 0):

```
l = []

s = input("Введите число: ")
s = int (s)
l=list(s)

a = l[0:3]
b = l[3:6]
```

или

```
l = []

s = int (input("Введите число: "))
l=list(s)

a = l[0:3]
b = l[3:6]
```

Comment: Этот код не будет работать.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = input('Введите число:')
a = int(s[:3])
b = int(s[3:6])
print(a, b)
print(a+b) # доп проверка, что они числа
```