# Как написать программу, которая выводит ошибку при вводе не целочисленного числа? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно написать программу, которая при вводе строки(str) выводит сообщение, что "Вы ввели не число"

```
a = input()
if type(a)==int:
    print('YES')
else:
    print('NO')
```

При вводе 1 или q ответ No

Comment: `input()` всегда возвращает строку, которую нужно [преобразовывать в число](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1157397) вручную, если вам нужно число

Comment: А нецелые числа можно вводить?

Comment: `not a.isdigit()` не?

Comment: @Evrik нет, т.к. могут быть отрицательные

Comment: тогда `not a[a[0]=='-':].isdigit()`, но с ограничением, что не может быть знака `+`

Comment: @Evrik До минуса может быть куча пробелов и т.п.

Comment: @nyekitka тогда так `not a.strip(' -+').isdigit()` ))

Comment: @Evrik а если + или - по середине?)

Comment: @nyekitka тогда это уже не целое число, а строка символов

Comment: А кто сказал, что её пользователь не может ввести? Тут как раз задача различить строку символов от числа

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы хотите принимать любые числа, то можно поступить так:

```
a = input()
try:
    int(a)
except ValueError:
    a = None
if a is None:
    print('NO')
else:
    print('YES')
```

Если же вы хотите принимать только положительные числа можно сделать код легче:

```
a = input()
if a.isdigit():
    print('YES')
else:
    print('NO')
```

Если же хотите числа с плавающей точкой использовать тоже, то в третьей строчке первого фрагмента кода `int(a)` замените на `float(a)`.

Comment: Благодарю. Не успел познакомиться с некоторыми свойствами.

Comment: Если считаете ответ верным, то вы его можете пометить верным слева сбоку от ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Введите строку, попытайтесь преобразовать в целое, если не вышло впишите в переменную `None` - признак неудачи:

```
s = input()
try:
    i = int(s)
except ValueError:
    i = None

if isinstance(i, int):
    print('YES')
else:
    print('NO')
```

Comment: Благодарю. Не успел познакомиться с некоторыми свойствами.

Answer (score 0):

Решение для Sololearn:

```py
num = input()
try:
    x = int(num)
except:
    print("Неверный ввод")
```

Comment: Следует отформатировать код, чтобы он мог выполниться, хотя по сути он мало чем отличается от предыдущих ответов.